# jQuery Mobile - Swiping - Stops working on new page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

So i have a basic code set up to work with jQuery Mobile, which on swipe left moves two specific divs and then moves them back on swipe right. Simple enough and it works just fine on the page it loads up on but when you click on a new page and it loads up the swipes no longer work.

Please see my code attached below for reference:-

```
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){
    $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", function(e){
            if (e.type === "swipeleft") {
                $("#headerContainer").css({left:'-60px'});
                $("#mainContainer").css({marginLeft:'0px'});
            } else if (e.type === "swiperight") {
                $("#headerContainer").css({left:'0px'});
                $("#mainContainer").css({marginLeft:'60px'});
            }
    });
});
```

I've tried looking all over for some kind of solution but to no avail, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `#headerContainer` and `#mainContainer` are unique or duplicated in each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem came from the way jQuery Mobile works. Since jQuery Mobile loads the pages through what seems to be ajax meant that the page didn't truly refresh and declare the divs again thus causing problems relative to ID's, therefore opting to Classes fixed this problem.